# Response status code does not indicate success: 504 (Gateway Timeout)/Task has been canceled exception while HttpClient.GetStringAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, ldap, dotnet-httpclient

I have an application which uses WebAPI for pulling out the LDAP data. It runs perfectly on my local machine, but since I publish the app refreshing the data doesn't work. I've done some research and it seems that the asynchronous task is having some sort of deadlock. Since I'm new to that whole threading/tasking stuff I need your advice how to setup and code everything correctly. If I make the exception handling more generic and instead of catching specific Exception-derived classes I end up with `Task has been canceled` (timeout?) error, currently it displays `Response status code does not indicate success: 504 (Gateway Timeout).`. I've tried defining HttpClient's timeout, configuring await on GetStringAsync, without any success.

Here's my code:

`Models\Partials\Person.cs:`

```
public async Task RefreshLDAP()
        {
            string URL = UserLib.LDAP_WS + login;

            #region other method
            //System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
            //client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, */*;q=0.1";
            //client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; de; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12";
            //string json_string = client.DownloadString(URL);
            #endregion

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                string json_string = "";
                try
                {
                    json_string =
                        await client.GetStringAsync(URL).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                // handle somehow
                throw new Exception(string.Format("TaskCanceledException threw an error: {0}",ex.Message));
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                // handle somehow
                throw new Exception(string.Format("HttpRequestException threw an error: {0}", ex.Message));
            }


                dynamic userInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json_string);

                first_name = userInfo.FirstName;
                last_name = userInfo.LastName;
                position = userInfo.Title;
                email = userInfo.Mail;

            }
        }
```

`Controlers\ProfileControler.cs:`

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Refresh()
        {
            var currentLogin = UserLib.GetLogin();
            var currentUser = (from user in ent.People where user.cecid == currentCecid select user).SingleOrDefault();
            if (currentUser == null)
                throw new Exception();

            await currentUser.RefreshLDAP(); 

            ent.SaveChanges();

            return View("Manage");
        }
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
System.Exception: HttpRequestException threw an error: Response status code does not indicate success: 504 (Gateway Timeout).
   at MyApp1.Models.Person.<RefreshLDAP>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MyApp1.Controllers.ClientsController.<Refresh>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Comment: Are you using `Task.Result` anywhere else in your code? Also, can the same `HttpClient` request take more than 30s if you call it from a unit test or a console app?

Comment: No, I don't use it at all. If I'd run it from console app then it would probably took less than 30s.

Comment: Could you show us the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Another thing, you are creating a `dynamic` object and you're setting them after deserialization. Are you sure they all return from your json?

Comment: I've added stack trace to the post. Yes, I'm pretty sure it's all returning from json since it's working locally perfectly.